# Error When Sending Array of Lists As A Request Body In Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

I get the following error in the Spring console:

`` WARN 1208 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Float>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Float>` out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 5] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0])] ``

When I pass this response body to my application locally using Postman Echo:

```
    {
        "timeslots": [
            [
                8.4,
                9.4,
                10.0,
                11.4,
                12.0,
                13.4,
                14.4,
                15.4,
                16.4,
                17.4,
                18.4,
                19.4
            ],
            [
                10.4,
                11.4,
                12.0
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my endpoint:

```
    @PutMapping(path = "/timeslots/id/{id}")
    public void updateTimeslotsById(@RequestBody ArrayList<Float>[] timeslots, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        Member member = this.memberService.getMemberById(id).orElseThrow(() ->
                new ApiRequestException("Cannot find member with this ID"));
        //member.setTimeslots(timeslots);
        this.memberService.updateMember(id, member);
    }
```

Comment: Your JSON is not a two-dimensional array of numbers. It's an array _of JSON objects with the property `timeslots`_ whose value is a two-dimensional array of numbers.

Comment: I tried the following syntax also, in order to pass just the 2D array but it threw the same error
`[
    [
        8.4,
        9.4,
        10.0,
        11.4,
        12.0,
        13.4,
        14.4,
        15.4,
        16.4,
        17.4,
        18.4,
        19.4
    ],
    [
        10.4,
        11.4,
        12.0
    ]
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receiver in your contoller method does not comply with json schema hence deserialization issue is coming.

Craete below custom class.

```
MyObject {
List<Float[]> timeslots;
//getter
//setter
}
```

Change your method signature to

```
public void updateTimeslotsById(@RequestBody MyObject timeslots, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
```

Comment: I have tried this solution at my side before responding. There is an extra ']' at end of json shared by you, this could be the reason or something very minor like this.